# "Invalid operands to binary expressions" Error

Tags: c

I keep getting this error:

> "Invalid operands to binary expressions ('int' and 'Primenumber'(aka
>   'struct number'))

on two lines that i've marked below with **'s. Whats wrong and how can I fix it? The code is for a data structure assignment.

```
typedef struct number
{
    int num[3];
} Primenumber;

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

Node *head = NULL;

int AddPrimeNumber(Primenumber x)
{
    Node *n;
    Node *newNode;
    //Create a new node
    newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    **newNode->data=x;**
    newNode->next=NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        n= head;
        while (n-> next != NULL)
        {
            n= n->next;
        }
        n->next= newNode;
    }
    return 0;
}

int SearchPrimeNumber(Primenumber x)
{
    int pos=0;
    Node *n = head;
    while (n != NULL)
    {
        **if (n->data ==x)**
        {
            return pos;
        }
        else
        {
            pos++;
            n= n->next;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int DisplayPrimeNumber()
{
    Node *n =head;
    while (n != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d -> ", n->data);
        n= n->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Why is `PrimeNumber` a three-number thingie?

Comment: You are comparing a scalar int (newNode->data) to a structure Primenumber x.  Did you mean (newNode->data = x.num[0])?

Comment: May be you mean `typedef strcut node {PrimeNumber data; struct node *next;} Node;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First time

```
newNode->data=x;
```

you are assigning an struct of `PrimeNumber` type to an `int`,

Second time you are comparing an struct of `PrimeNumber` type to an `int`

```
n->data ==x
```

both are wrong, may be what you want is

```
typedef struct Node {
    PrimeNumber data;
    struct Node *next;
};
```

the assignment part will be ok, but you will have to elaborate on the comparison part I would use a function

```
areEqualPrimeNumbers(PrimeNumber *x, PrimeNumber *y)
{
    return ((x->num[0] == y->num[0]) && (x->num[1] == y->num[1]) && (x->num[2] == y->num[2]));
}
```

or if you want to use `memcmp`

```
areEqualPrimeNumbers(PrimeNumber *x, PrimeNumber *y)
{
    return (memcmp(x->num, y->num, sizeof(x->num)) == 0);
}
```

and then

```
areEqualNodes(&x, &(n->data));
```

the `memcmp` version is better since it does not depend on the definition of `PrimeNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

`newNode->data` is of type `int` while `x` is of type `Primenumber` (`struct number`). C provides no operation on entire structure except assignment.

Answer (score 0):

In first **s you are trying to assign `x` of type `Primenumber` to `n->data` of type `int`;This is your first mistake.

In second **s you are trying the same for comparing;This is your second mistake.

And,please mark your errors with simple `//error` comments,not using **s ;).

Answer (score 0):

```
// always comment your code so others (or yourself later) 
// do not have to 'reverse engineer' it

// <-- declutter code by just defining a struct type, not typedef struct
struct PrimeNumber
{
    int num[3];
};

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

// <-- due to better definition of struct, need to use the 'struct' modifier
struct Node *head = NULL;

// <-- pass as pointer so compiler does not generate two hidden calls to memcpy())
// <-- nor allocate memory space that is unusable for anything else
//int AddPrimeNumber(PrimeNumber x)
// <-- due to better definition of struct, need to use the 'struct' modifier
int AddPrimeNumber(struct PrimeNumber* x)
{
    // <-- due to better definition of struct, need to use the 'struct' modifier
    // <-- initialize local variables to a 'safe' value
    struct Node *n = NULL;
    struct Node *newNode = NULL;

    //Create a new node
    // <-- always check the returned value from malloc() to assure operation successful
    if( NULL == (newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node)) ) )
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    // <-- x contains 3 integer fields, newNode contains 1 integer field.
    // <-- what were you expecting to happen?
    // <-- perhaps you meant: newNode->data = x->num[0]; which only copies one int, not all three
    **newNode->data=x;**
    newNode->next=NULL;


    if (head == NULL) // this handles special case of empty list
    { 
        head = newNode;
    }

    else
    { // else, list already contains one or more nodes
        n= head;
        while (n->next != NULL)
        {
            // step to next node in linked list
            n= n->next;
        }
        // <-- currently 'n' points to last node in linked list
        // <-- add new node to end of linked list
        n->next= newNode;
    }
    return 0;
} // end function: AddPrimeNumber

// similar considerations need to be applied to the other posted function
```

Comment: Thank you, I will keep in mind to add comments! Error has been sorted and program working well, thanks again for your help.